# How do I sign an XML file in VB.NET using PKCS#7?

Tags: vb.net, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have to sign an XML file in PKCS#7 using a SHA-1 hashing algorithm and a RSA encryption.
I used:

```
Dim MessageContent As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("Msg.xml")
Dim latin1 = Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(&H6FAF)
Dim bytes As Byte() = latin1.GetBytes(MessageContent)
Dim certstore = New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)
certstore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly)
Dim cert = certstore.Certificates(1) 'This is the certificate I want
Dim encodedsignedcms As Byte() = Firma(bytes, cert)
```

With the function Firma

```
Function Firma(ByVal msg As Byte(), ByVal cert As X509Certificate2)
    Dim contentinfo = New Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.ContentInfo(msg)
    Dim signedcms = New Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms(contentinfo)
    Dim cmssigner = New Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.CmsSigner(cert)
    signedcms.ComputeSignature(cmssigner)
    Return signedcms.Encode()
End Function
```

This code throws an error at `signedcms.ComputeSignature(cmssigner)` that says:

> A certificate chain could not be built to a trusted root authority.

I checked the Local Computer Trusted Root Certificates in mmc.exe>Certificates but I could find the root certificate that I installed to pair with my signing certificate.

Have you already seen this error? Since I installed the root certificate moments ago, do I have to "update" somehow Visual Studio?

P.S: Sorry but I'm new to cryptography and partially Visual Basic, so if you could keep it simple, you would do me a favour.

Comment: Did you supply all the intermediate certificates (if any)? Just the root cert is not enough if the chain cannot be build.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this line.

```
cmssigner.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.EndCertOnly
```

It happened I really didn't need the certificates chain.